# Java | Jframe | Generar con anclaje a la derecha de la pantalla

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Buenas tardes.

Quiero generar un main jframe que al instanciarlo salga anclado, automaticamente, a la derecha de mi display , es una desktop aplication.

Quiero que cuando aparezca salga de ese lado asi automatico. [Con su alto y anclaje automatico.]
[http://www.mediafire.com/view/dxnx11j0kecrcu9/Sin+título.jpg](http://www.mediafire.com/view/dxnx11j0kecrcu9/Sin+t%C3%ADtulo.jpg)

Gracias de antemano por sus ayudas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueden servirte básicamente 3 lineas:

```
Dimension pantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setSize( 300, (int) pantalla.getHeight() );
setLocation( (int) pantalla.getWidth() - getWidth(), 0 );
```

Justo al abrir (*Yosemite & Mint*)

[image: Running Yosemite And Mint]

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo habia conseguido de una manera mas engorroso y con mas lineas, tu manera es ams simple y limpia, te agradezco.