# JAVA | JFrame | Frame = [ alto de un display ] menos [ Alto de barra de tareas de widows ]

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, interfaz-gráfica

Anteriormente formule esta pregunta: --> 
[Java | Jframe | Generar con anclaje a la derecha de la pantalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86910/java-jframe-generar-con-anclaje-a-la-derecha-de-la-pantalla/87076#87076)

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es [ Bueno, el alto ya lo tengo gracias a Johnny que me lo resolvio ] que el alto del JFrame no tome en cuenta la barra de tareas de Windows.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto puedes ir jugando e ir viendo la posición:

```
Dimension pantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize( (int) pantalla.getWidth(), (int) pantalla.getHeight() - 40 );
        setLocation( (int) pantalla.getWidth() - getWidth(), 0 );
```

En el seteo del size, **setSize**, en el segundo parámetro le vas restando alto e ir ajustando a tu pantalla. No se si es eso lo que buscas o estoy entendiendo mal la pregunta